# Prove that $A$ $ =\{ \bigcup^{n}_{i=1}\bigcap^{m}_{j=1}A_{i,j} $ with $ n,m ∈ N,∀i,j: A_{i,j} ∈ E$ $or A^c_{i,j} ∈ E \} $ is an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, lebesgue-measure

For a set $Ω$ consider a generator $ Ε ⊆ Pot(Ω)$ we have to show that the system of sets
**A** $ =\{ \bigcup^{n}_{i=1}\bigcap^{m}_{j=1}A_{i,j} $ with $ n,m ∈ N,∀i,j: A_{i,j} ∈ E$ $or A^c_{i,j} ∈ E \} $, defines an algebra on $Ω$.

So basically we have to show that **A** is a ring and then $Ω ∈ $ **A** to conclude that it is an algebra. I could go by the properties to show that a set is a ring but i am confused with the big union and intersection which are given so i am not quite sure how to use due to these. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\text{Pot}(\Omega)$?

Comment: a sample space is the Pot$(Ω)$ , which is the set of all possible outcomes. Consider it just as a set which contains all the possible subsets of $Ω$ space